How to load a json file properly for working with its data in Python?
I've used most of methods to load a json and the results I got didn't meet my needs. When I load the file with pandas read_json, I get a dataframe with the index and all fields in a single line, as a string. Here's the two calls I do that doesn't work for me:
import json
import pandas as pd
#Open and read the JSON file

with open('faturamento.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    print(d)


fat = pd.read_json("faturamento.json")

And faturamento.json is:
{
    "faturamento": [
        {
            "day": "2024-09-01",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-02",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-03",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-04",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-05",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-06",
            "fat": "1000",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-07",
            "fat": "   0",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-08",
            "fat": "1500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-09",
            "fat": "1500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-10",
            "fat": "1500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-11",
            "fat": "1500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-12",
            "fat": "1500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-13",
            "fat": "   0",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-14",
            "fat": "   0",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-15",
            "fat": "2500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-16",
            "fat": "2500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-17",
            "fat": "2500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-18",
            "fat": "2500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-19",
            "fat": "2500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-20",
            "fat": "   0",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-21",
            "fat": "   0",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-22",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-23",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-24",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-25",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-26",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-27",
            "fat": " 500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-28",
            "fat": "1500",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-29",
            "fat": "   0",
            "business_day": "FALSE"
        },
        {
            "day": "2024-09-30",
            "fat": "3500",
            "business_day": "TRUE"
        }
    ]
}

I thought that read_json would do the trick. How can I really have a dataframe with three columns: day, fat, business_day?

Two options:
df = pd.json_normalize(pd.read_json("faturamento.json")["faturamento"])

or
with open("faturamento.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame(d["faturamento"])

Both will output:
           day   fat business_day
0   2024-09-01   500         TRUE
1   2024-09-02   500         TRUE
2   2024-09-03   500         TRUE
3   2024-09-04   500         TRUE
4   2024-09-05   500         TRUE
5   2024-09-06  1000        FALSE
6   2024-09-07     0        FALSE
7   2024-09-08  1500         TRUE
8   2024-09-09  1500         TRUE
9   2024-09-10  1500         TRUE
10  2024-09-11  1500         TRUE
11  2024-09-12  1500         TRUE
12  2024-09-13     0        FALSE
13  2024-09-14     0        FALSE
14  2024-09-15  2500         TRUE
15  2024-09-16  2500         TRUE
16  2024-09-17  2500         TRUE
17  2024-09-18  2500         TRUE
18  2024-09-19  2500         TRUE
19  2024-09-20     0        FALSE
20  2024-09-21     0        FALSE
21  2024-09-22   500         TRUE
22  2024-09-23   500         TRUE
23  2024-09-24   500         TRUE
24  2024-09-25   500         TRUE
25  2024-09-26   500         TRUE
26  2024-09-27   500         TRUE
27  2024-09-28  1500        FALSE
28  2024-09-29     0        FALSE
29  2024-09-30  3500         TRUE


you need to use pd.json_normalize:
with open(file) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    
df = pd.json_normalize(data['faturamento'])

Output:
           day   fat    business_day
0   2024-09-01   500         TRUE
1   2024-09-02   500         TRUE
2   2024-09-03   500         TRUE
3   2024-09-04   500         TRUE
4   2024-09-05   500         TRUE
5   2024-09-06  1000        FALSE
6   2024-09-07     0        FALSE
7   2024-09-08  1500         TRUE
8   2024-09-09  1500         TRUE
9   2024-09-10  1500         TRUE
10  2024-09-11  1500         TRUE
11  2024-09-12  1500         TRUE
12  2024-09-13     0        FALSE
13  2024-09-14     0        FALSE
14  2024-09-15  2500         TRUE
15  2024-09-16  2500         TRUE
16  2024-09-17  2500         TRUE
17  2024-09-18  2500         TRUE
18  2024-09-19  2500         TRUE
19  2024-09-20     0        FALSE
20  2024-09-21     0        FALSE
21  2024-09-22   500         TRUE
22  2024-09-23   500         TRUE
23  2024-09-24   500         TRUE
24  2024-09-25   500         TRUE
25  2024-09-26   500         TRUE
26  2024-09-27   500         TRUE
27  2024-09-28  1500        FALSE
28  2024-09-29     0        FALSE
29  2024-09-30  3500         TRUE

